# How can I develop multiple widgets for a WordPress theme?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I'm developing a new theme for WP and I want to add different sorts of widgets and different classes, because I want these widgets to look different (for example footer widgets should have another styling, and now I can only target them with the "widget class", one class for all).

```
function create_widget($name, $id, $description) {

  register_sidebar(array(

'name' => __( $name ),

    'id' => $id,
    'description' => __( $description ),
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
  ));

}
```

Is this even possible or do I have to delete my  class "widgets" and adding new classes everytime to the new widget?

Answer (score 4):

When registering a sidebar, you can use certain placeholders for the widget classes. Here's an example taken from the codex:

```
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
```

It's the lack of `%1$s` and `%2$s` that is causing your issues. When in doubt always read the documentation on the codex and the developer hub/handbooks

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function create_widget($name, $id, $description) {

  register_sidebar(array(

'name' => __( $name ),

    'id' => $id,
    'description' => __( $description ),
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget widget_' . $name . '" >',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
  ));

}
```

This way you will have the `widget` class wrapper for your widgets and also the `widget_$name` class, that you use from CSS.
Or you can completely remove the `widget` CSS class if you plan to do that, and everything looks great when you test.

Make sure you understand what CSS styles you will loose after you remove  the `widget` class. But this is possible.

Answer (score -1):

To add another sidebar you simply need to register another instance. If you are registering more than one, then you will also need to name them. Change your functions.php file to look like the following. Take care to add in the extra line that specifies the name of your sidebar. Once these are functions are defined, you will notice the extra sidebar appear in the WordPress Dashboard under the Appearance > Widgets option. It’s here that you can drag and drop all your widgets into your various sidebars.

'sidebar 1',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '

### ',
   'after_title' => '

'
    ));

   register_sidebar(array(
   'name' => 'footer sidebar 1',
   'before_widget' => '',
   'after_widget' => '',
   'before_title' => '

### ',
   'after_title' => '

'
   ));

}?>